# PDO Exception not being thrown for trigger errors

Tags: php, oracle, triggers, pdo

I am using PDO with the OCI driver.  A particular `INSERT` query of mine is causing a trigger error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "FOO.BAR", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FOO.BAR'
```

However, an exception is not being thrown when this happens.  I am using `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, and exceptions are thrown fine for standard query syntax errors and such, but *not* for any error originating from a trigger.

The call to `$st->execute()` does not return `FALSE` in this case either.  Also, `$st->errorInfo()` and `$st->errorCode()` are both unhelpful, as well:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
}
string(5) "00000"
```

How can I get PDO to throw an exception when a trigger error happens?  Or, if that's impossible, how can I programmatically detect when this happens by other means?  The only way I even know that an error happened in the first place (aside from the database not being updated) is that `$st->rowCount()` is reporting 0.  But this is not a unique or reliable way by itself of determining whether an error occurred...

Comment: Could you share the PHP code triggering the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible.  Triggers (and events) are run on the DB based on DB actions and are not directly tied your query--at least as seen on the PHP side.  Your PDO query is succeeding and that's all your statement will ever know, the fact that a trigger was set up to do something based on the results of whatever your statement did to some table is irrelevant.

The options you have are:

1. write another query to confirm the success of whatever the trigger was supposed to do
2. possibly wrap the initial query into a stored procedure that runs the query and verifys the success of the trigger action.  Then call that stored proc instead of running the query directly.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicions.