# PDO doesn't throw an error in case of a trigger error

Tags: php, pdo

Have trigger on table with `DELETE` event. And special have and error in this. When delete row manually receive an error, but when trying to delete via PDO, receive success statement, and row successfully delete. Don't understand where problem.

**Trigger code**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user` TRIGGER `TR_VM_users_AD` AFTER DELETE ON `VM_users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    /* Archive profile */   
    INSERT INTO VM_users_archive (date_time_created, date_time_modified, imsi, msisdn, `password`, skip_password, email, send_email, is_header_enabled, ivr_lang, sms_lang, ussd_lang, status_id)
    VALUES (OLD.date_time_created, OLD.date_time_modified, OLD.imsi, OLD.msisdn, OLD.`password`, OLD.skip_password, OLD.email, OLD.send_email, OLD.is_header_enabled, OLD.ivr_lang, OLD.sms_lang, OLD.ussd_lang, OLD.status_id);
    
        /* Delete personal blacklist */
        DELETE FROM VM_personal_blacklist WHERE callednumber = OLD.msisdn;
        
        /*Delete greetings */
        DELETE FROM VM_greetings WHERE called_number = OLD.msisdn;
END;
```

**MYSQL error when trying to delete manually**

```
mysql> Delete from VM_users where msisdn = 810044168;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'callednumber' in 'where clause'
mysql>
```

**php code**

```
try
{
    $transactionStartTime = microtime(true);
    
    $this->db->pdo->beginTransaction();
    
    $queryDeleteProfile = 'DELETE FROM VM_users WHERE msisdn = :msisdn';
    
    if (!$this->db->preparedQuery($queryDeleteProfile, ['msisdn' => $msisdn]))
    {
        $this->db->pdo->rollBack();
        
        return false;
    }
    
    $this->db->pdo->commit();
    
    $transactionEndTime = round((microtime(true) - $transactionStartTime), 2);
    
    $this->utility->loggerAll($this->logPrefix, __FUNCTION__, $this->logLevel, 3, 'Profile deleted. msisdn: ' . $msisdn . ', transactionEndTime: ' . $transactionEndTime);  
}
catch (\PDOException $ex)
{
    $this->utility->loggerAll($this->logPrefix, __FUNCTION__, $this->logLevel, 1, 'Failed to delete profile!. msisdn: ' . $msisdn . ', errorMessage: ' . $ex->getMessage());
    
    $this->db->pdo->rollBack();
    
    return false;
}

public function preparedQuery($query, $params)
{
    try
    {
        $this->checkConnection();
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        
        if (!$stmt->execute($params))
        {
            $this->utility->loggerAll($this->logPrefix, __FUNCTION__, $this->logLevel, 1, 'Failed to execute prepared query! ' . $this->pdo->errorInfo()[2] . ', query: ' . $query . ', params: ' . json_encode($params));
            
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $this->utility->loggerAll($this->logPrefix, __FUNCTION__, $this->logLevel, 1, 'Failed to execute prepared query! ' . $e->getMessage() . ', query: ' . $query . ', params: ' . json_encode($params));
        
        return false;
    }
    
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: In one delete query you use `callednumber`, and in the other `called_number`. Is that correct?

Comment: It is special error, to see reaction when execute via PDO

Comment: When execute via native mysqli, i receive error, but PDO say success and delete row

Comment: You should probably explain that in the question.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13647655/9473764

Answer (score -1):

Oh it was my big mistake, with error in PDO all ok. Problem wath because, from php script trying to delete row which already was deleted from DB, and as result was no error.

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM VM_users WHERE msisdn = :msisdn';

var_dump($db->preparedQuery($query, ['msisdn' => $msisdn]));

DBModule: preparedQuery(): CRITICAL: Failed to execute prepared query! SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'callednumber' in 'where clause', query: DELETE FROM VM_users WHERE msisdn = :msisdn, params: {"msisdn":810044172}
```